# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found Issue when Trying to read url from Yahoo Finance given Stock Symbol

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, urllib2, urllib3

I am trying to write a program that will help me with accounting work. I am trying to pull information by using stock prices for companies over time. I am utilizing `urllib.request` to read and open URLs, but I can't get around this 404 issue, despite the URL existing. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried changing the `import` statement to:

```py
import urllib.request as ur
```

so that I can also try:

```py
read_data = ur.urlopen(url_is).read() 
soup_is = BeautifulSoup(read_data, 'lxml')
```

but that came up with [the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HU6U.png).

Comment: Can you include the `url_is` URL please - is it https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup ? If it's that, it seems to work ok with [the `requests` module](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp) (like *`BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup').content)`*). Do you need to stick to `urlopen`?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

To extract historical market data in 4 lines you can use [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) package.

Check code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-yahoo-finance-stock-price#main.py).

```py
import yfinance as yf

mar = yf.Ticker("MAR")

# get historical market data
hist = mar.history(period="1mo")

print(hist)
```

Output:

```
                                 Open  ...  Stock Splits
Date                                   ...              
2023-02-08 00:00:00-05:00  173.312661  ...           0.0
2023-02-09 00:00:00-05:00  175.148339  ...           0.0
2023-02-10 00:00:00-05:00  172.734024  ...           0.0
2023-02-13 00:00:00-05:00  171.626626  ...           0.0
2023-02-14 00:00:00-05:00  175.307981  ...           0.0
2023-02-15 00:00:00-05:00  180.495778  ...           0.0
2023-02-16 00:00:00-05:00  176.984033  ...           0.0
2023-02-17 00:00:00-05:00  174.220532  ...           0.0
2023-02-21 00:00:00-05:00  170.359599  ...           0.0
2023-02-22 00:00:00-05:00  169.641289  ...           0.0
2023-02-23 00:00:00-05:00  171.529999  ...           0.0
2023-02-24 00:00:00-05:00  169.470001  ...           0.0
2023-02-27 00:00:00-05:00  171.759995  ...           0.0
2023-02-28 00:00:00-05:00  169.559998  ...           0.0
2023-03-01 00:00:00-05:00  169.419998  ...           0.0
2023-03-02 00:00:00-05:00  169.389999  ...           0.0
2023-03-03 00:00:00-05:00  171.850006  ...           0.0
2023-03-06 00:00:00-05:00  173.289993  ...           0.0
2023-03-07 00:00:00-05:00  175.580002  ...           0.0

[19 rows x 7 columns]
```

Also in your case, the problem may be due to the fact that your request is blocked.

You can read [Reducing the chance of being blocked while web scraping](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/) blog post to figure out how to bypass these blocks.